# SQL Server python from server a to server b - query server a, insert into server b

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server servers on which I'm trying to run:

On server A database A, I'm running a SQL query to get some data, the data which I have now from the query, I would like to insert into server B database B. (both are different servers different SQL users and pass)

I was looking at examples and I could not find anything to do as above, all are doing using same server but two different databases in my case I have two different servers on which I need to insert the data.

Anyone can help with some examples how can I query A and insert into B?

Comment: Is there a possibility to login on server b and execute a stored procedure?
In the stored procedure, you can write logic to read data from the server a and save it in server b. Taking all the data from server a to application server and returning the data from application server to server b is highly error prone.

Comment: You can do this in the database.  You need to learn about linked servers:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check pyodbc connector in python.
Something like that should work:

```
import pyodbc
sqlserver_base_A = pyodbc.connect(driver='{'+sqlserver_driver+'}', server='your_server_A', database='yourDB_A', uid=sqlserver_user, pwd=sqlserver_passwd)
A_cursor = sqlserver_base_A.cursor()

sqlserver_base_B = pyodbc.connect(driver='{'+sqlserver_driver+'}', server='your_server_B', database='yourDB_B', uid=sqlserver_user, pwd=sqlserver_passwd)
B_cursor = sqlserver_base_B.cursor()

query='SELECT * FROM DB_A.schema.TABLE'
A_cursor.execute(query)
rows_A = sqlserver_cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows_A:
    new_query='INSERT INTO DB_B VALUES '+row+';'
    B_cursor.execute(new_query)

sqlserver_base_A.commit()
A_cursor.close()
B_cursor.close()
```

Maybe you need to adjust query for inserting into database B, nevertheless something like that should work.